# Como realizar uma consulta em HQL no C#?

Tags: c#, hql

Preciso criar uma consulta HQL dentro de um método em C#. A estrutura é mais ou menos assim:
Tenho o método:

```
IList<int>GetListYear(Guid educationalInstitutionId, Guid academicLevelId, Guid? locationId, Guid? programOfferedId)
{
    //Implementar a consulta HQL
}
```

E tenho a consulta em HQL:

```
"select distinct ConclusionYear
    from AlumniProgramOffered
    inner join AlumniSignup
    inner join ProgramOffered
    inner join Program
    where AlumniSignup.EducationalInstitution.Identity = educationalInstitutionId
and Program.AcademicLevel.Identity = academicLevelId
and ProgramOffered.Location.Identity = locationId or locationId is null
and ProgramOffered.Identity = programOfferedId or programOfferedId is null"
```

Como posso montar essa estrutura afim de unir a consulta HQL com os parâmetros que recebi do meu método?

Answer (score 3):

cara ficaria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
IList<int> GetListYear(Guid educationalInstitutionId, Guid academicLevelId, Guid? locationId, Guid? programOfferedId)
{
    StringBuilder hql = new StringBuilder();

    hql.Append(" select distinct ConclusionYear ");
    hql.Append(" from AlumniProgramOffered ");
    hql.Append(" inner join AlumniSignup ");
    hql.Append(" inner join ProgramOffered ");
    hql.Append(" inner join Program ");
    hql.Append(" where AlumniSignup.EducationalInstitution.Identity = :educationalInstitutionId ");
    hql.Append(" and Program.AcademicLevel.Identity = :academicLevelId ");
    hql.Append(" and ProgramOffered.Location.Identity = :locationId or locationId is null ");
    hql.Append(" and ProgramOffered.Identity = :programOfferedId or programOfferedId is null" ");

    Query query = Session.CreateHqlQuery(hql.ToString());
    query.SetParameter("educationalInstitutionId", educationalInstitutionId);
    query.SetParameter("academicLevelId", academicLevelId);
    query.SetParameter("locationId", locationId);
    query.SetParameter("programOfferedId", programOfferedId);

    return query.ToList<int>();
}
```

Comment: Olá @ThiagoFalcão. Tentei usar `Query query = Session.CreateHqlQuery(hql.ToString());` mas não reconhece e pede pra fazer a referência. Fiz a referência com `NHibernate.Engine`, que foi sugerida, mas não funcionou.

Comment: certo, tente mudar a parte que criar a query para assim:      Query query = session.createQuery(hql.ToString()); caso esteja algo incorreto, tente colocar a primeira letra maiuscula de session e createQuery. o site que tem a referencia está fora do ar :( 
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/pt-BR/html/queryhql.html

Comment: Não deu certo @ThiagoFalcão. Ele não reconhece a classe `Query`.